# Entity Framework 5 recursive relations

Tags: entity-framework, parent-child

```
CREATE TABLE ConfigurationItem
(  
  OID BIGINT NOT NULL
  ,ParentItemOID BIGINT 
);

ALTER TABLE ConfigurationItem ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CONFIGURATIONITEM PRIMARY KEY (OID);

ALTER TABLE ConfigurationItem ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CONFIGURATIONITEM_PARENTITEMOID FOREIGN KEY (ParentItemOID ) REFERENCES CONFIGURATIONITEM(OID);
```

Every time fetch data ConfigurationItem I would like to get
parent ConfigurationItem 
and List of child ConfigurationItems
and no recursion.

This was the entity created

```
[Table("ConfigurationItem", Schema = "dbo")]
public partial class ConfigurationItem : TaggableItem
{
  public Int64 OID { get; set; }
  public Int64? ParentItemOID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ParentItemOID")]
  public ConfigurationItem Parent;

  [InverseProperty("ParentItemOID")]
  //Not a virtual because it is need to be marshalled via WCF
  public List<ConfigurationItem> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

I can't make this to work.

Example following errors happen:

```
InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
HResult=-2146232060
Message=Invalid column name 'ConfigurationItem_OID'.
Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
ErrorCode=-2146232060
Class=16
LineNumber=32
Number=207
Procedure=""
Server=localhost
State=1
```

What would be the correct way to make this work in Entity framework?

Comment: Change `InverseProperty` parameter to `"Parent"`

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Thanks for your proposal, but now I get this: The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Children' on type 'ConfigurationItem' is not valid. The property 'Parent' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'ConfigurationItem'.  Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original exception stems from the default naming convention used by EF. Either rename the OID property in the ConfigurationItem class to Configuration_OID or use the Column annotation on the OID property to indicate that you want to override the default naming convention for that column, e.g. [Column("OID")].

I have a schema with a self-referential table like this and I haven't found it necessary to use the InverseProperty annotation, so you may be able to just get rid of it.